# How would I kill a process outside it's loop in a winform application?

Tags: c#, kill-process

here is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Wraith
{
    public partial class WraithClient : Form
    {
        


        public WraithClient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        

        private void test_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Process myProcess1 = new Process())
            {
                myProcess1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                myProcess1.StartInfo.FileName = "test.exe";
                myProcess1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess1.Start();
            }
        }

        private void kill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myProcess1.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

the error I recieve is: "Error  CS0103  The name 'myProcess1' does not exist in the current context"
What I'm trying to do is to when the user clicks the kill button it will end the test.exe process.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `myProcess1` is only visible inside the `using` block. Re-read your lessons on variable scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access `myProcess1` outside of the `using` statement. The only way that you would be able to kill that process would be by setting `myProcess1` up as a global variable. That being said, I would highly discourage going that route with processes. The best option would be to have the user select the process in the application so that you can ensure a running process prior to killing.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, move the declaration of `myProcess` from local to class level:

```
private Process myProcess1;

private void test_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myProcess == null) 
    {
        myProcess1 = new Process();
        myProcess1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess1.StartInfo.FileName = "test.exe";
        myProcess1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess1.Start();
    }
}

private void kill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myProcess != null) 
    {
        myProcess1.Kill();
    }
}
```